# Adapt global PAGE_SIZE setting in Django REST Framework's browsable API to a different local PAGE_SIZE setting

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We are using the Django REST Framework with [pagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) and a [browsable API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/).

The global parameter for the page size in `settings.py` is set to `10000` in order to get higher performance when accessing the API via HTTP requests which works well:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": ["django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend"],
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination",
    "PAGE_SIZE": 10000,
}
```

Now the problem is that this is directly linked to the [browsable API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/) which also lists `10000` entries per page. This of course takes very long or even breaks within certain browsers.

Is there a way to change this behaviour locally for the browsable API?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to use a different settings file for local purposes?

Comment: There isn't anything special about the api(s) that the Browsable UI calls, so you get the same behavior.  The best you could do is write your own version of PageNumberPagination, detect if the request is coming from the Browseable UI, and override the page size.

Comment: @JPG: Can you explain this a bit further?

Comment: @Andrew: Could you provide an example?

Comment: When you say "locally", what do you mean.   And I'm a bit to busy to write that for you, but... the DRF documentation handily includes an example of customizing pagination.  Check that and the base class and see what you can overrided and how to access the request.  I'm sure there is a way.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will give it a try and post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using a custom [pagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) class e. g. in `utils.py`:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination


class AdjustableResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = "page_size"
    max_page_size = 10000
```

which can be used in `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .utils import AdjustableResultsSetPagination


class RestrictedViewSet:
    """
    Parent view that restricts viewers without authentication.
    """
    # ...
    pagination_class = AdjustableResultsSetPagination


class DeviceViewSet(RestrictedViewSet, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ...
    pass
```

and allows to set the `page_size` manually, e. g. via:

```
GET /api/addresses/?page_size=5
```

Thanks to Andrew for pointing me in the right direction!